# What means a Party being a ‘Witness’ of a contract and what are its implications?

Tags: daml

I'm making some exercises to get to know Daml and one of the exercises involves the transfer of an Asset from a Party to another Party. Everything works correctly, but I’ve noticed that the owner of the previous Asset contract is marked as ‘Witness’ of the new Asset contract  (At `Assets.Asset:Asset`, the contract with ID `#8:2` has `Alice` marked with a `W`, `Witness`).

[image]

I was intrigued with that. What does it means a Party being a ‘Witness’ of a contract and what are its implications? I didn’t found an answer for it in the documentation…

Here is some of the code I’ve used. I’ve applied the propose-accept pattern.

```
template HolderRole
  with
    operator : Party
    holder : Party
  where
    signatory operator, holder
    key (operator, holder) : (Party, Party)
    maintainer key._1

    controller holder can
      nonconsuming ProposeAssetTransfer : ContractId AssetTransferProposal
        with
          receiver : Party
          assetCid : ContractId Asset
        do
          exercise assetCid ProposeTransfer with receiver
      
      nonconsuming AcceptAssetTransfer : ContractId Asset
        with
          assetTransferProposalCid : ContractId AssetTransferProposal
        do
          exercise assetTransferProposalCid AssetTransferProposal_Accept

template Asset
  with
    issuer : Party
    owner : Party
    symbol : Text
    quantity : Decimal
  where
    signatory issuer, owner

    controller owner can
        ProposeTransfer : ContractId AssetTransferProposal
      with
        receiver : Party
      do
        create AssetTransferProposal with receiver, asset = this, assetCid = self

template AssetTransferProposal
  with
    receiver : Party
    asset : Asset
    assetCid : ContractId Asset
  where
    signatory asset.owner, asset.issuer

    controller receiver can
      AssetTransferProposal_Accept : ContractId Asset
        do
          create asset with owner = receiver

assetTransferTest = script do
  ...

  -- Transfer an Asset to another Party
  assetTransferProposalCid <- submit alice do
    exerciseByKeyCmd @HolderRole (operator, alice) ProposeAssetTransfer
      with receiver = bob, assetCid = assetCid

  -- Accept a transfer
  submit bob do
    exerciseByKeyCmd @HolderRole (operator, bob) AcceptAssetTransfer
      with assetTransferProposalCid = assetTransferProposalCid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `Alice` saw the creation of the new contract (`#8:2`) because she was a party to the old contract (`#6:2`) at the time it was consumed by `Bob` exercising `AcceptAssetTransfer` on `HolderRole`. The implications are that `Alice` could see that `Bob` became the new owner of `Asset` but will not see any future events that involve `Asset` such as it being archived as a result of sending the asset to another Party.

Additionally even though `Alice` saw/witnessed the creation of the new contract she cannot query for it after the one time event where she witnessed it.

Sometimes the docs are a bit hard to search so here's some relevant links:

- [A simple overview of the meaning of S, O, W, and D in the Script output](https://docs.daml.com/daml/daml-studio.html#scenario-and-daml-script-results)
- [The ledger privacy model](https://docs.daml.com/concepts/ledger-model/ledger-privacy.html)
- [A more detailed explanation on witnessing and divulgence](https://docs.daml.com/concepts/local-ledger.html#divulged-actions-do-not-induce-order)
- [An explanation of contract consumption in general](https://docs.daml.com/daml/reference/choices.html#contract-consumption)

As this question was also asked simultaneously on our forum [further discussion may be located here](https://discuss.daml.com/t/what-means-a-party-being-a-witness-of-a-contract-and-what-are-its-implications/2153).